# Where I can find documentation on kendoGrid columns.format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I found the following page about columns.format on Kendo UI jQuery API:

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.format

In the documentation it give a couple of examples of the format values:

```
format: "{0: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}"

format: "{0:c}"
```

But where I can find an explanation of what values can be specified for format? For example,

- How would I specify I wanted to format a number as percentage to two decimal places?
- What does the 0 mean in `{0:c}`?
- Why is format represented as `{0:c}`? What does the `:` signify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{0:c}` is the syntax for the kendo.format method. `0` means the first value which you want to format, `c` means that it will be formatted as a currency value. `:` is just a separator between value position and the format syntax. Here you can see an example with two values passed to kendo.format:

```
console.log(kendo.format("{0:c} - {1:c}", 12, 24)); // outputs "$12.00 - $24.00"
```

Example from: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/format

For percentage format, you can use `p` format:

> "p"—Renders a percentage (number is multiplied by 100).

```
format: "{0:p}"
```

For example, the value 0.2614 will be displayed as 26.14 %

You can find more explanation about kendo formatting on: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/globalization/intl/numberformatting